# How to correct standard errors of a two stage least squares

Tags: r, python, 2sls

Can you demo a working example, in python (pandas or numpy) or R, how you can correct the standard errors on a 2sls. Most resources say that the software will do that automatically for you, but I would like to see how it actually works in practice.

Currently I have a system of equations with 2 endogenous and 2 exogenous variables.